# Can we perform navigation between Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project page and a Windows Phone 8.1 project page under same solution?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am working in Windows Phone application in which I have two projects one is Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 and another is Windows Phone 8.1. I want to navigate from a xaml page in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project to Windows Phone 8.1 Project on a button click and then return back to the page. Is there any possible way to do that?

Thanks,
Ekta

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of their types, there is no way to directly navigate to a page in another app on Windows Phone. Your best option is to declare a URI association in the target app that the source app can launch with - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx) for details.

As for returning to the source app, you should try to leverage the system back key if at all possible. However, if it's not going to be obvious to the user that she should hit the back key, you have two options:

1. Use [Application.Current.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.exit.aspx) to close the target app, which will
       return the user to the last session in the back stack, which should
       be the source app (unless the user task-switched in the interim).
2. Register a URI association in the source app and navigate back to
       that from the target. Note that the process of registering and
       handling invocation of URI association activation is different in WP
       Silverlight apps - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

The difference between the two approaches is that if you Exit, the target app will be terminated and removed from the back stack whereas launching a URI association results in a new forward navigation and will leave the target app in the back stack.